# Why can't I use this nested lambda expression?

Tags: c#, lambda

I'm trying to maintain a list of unique models from a variety of queries. Unfortunately, the equals method of our models are not defined, so I couldn't use a hash map easily.

As a quick fix I used the following code:

```
public void AddUnique(
    List<Model> source,
    List<Model> result)
{
    if (result != null)
    {
        if (result.Count > 0
            && source != null
            && source.Count > 0)
        {
            source.RemoveAll(
                s => result.Contains(
                    r => r.ID == s.ID));
        }

        result.AddRange(source);
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, this does not work. When I step throught the code, I find that even though I've checked to make sure that there was at least one `Model` with the same `ID` in both `source` and `result`, the `RemoveAll(Predicate<Model>)` line does not change the number of items in `source`. What am I missing?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The above code shouldn't even compile, as `Contains` expects a `Model`, not a predicate.

You can use Any() instead:

```
source.RemoveAll(s => result.Any(r => r.ID == s.ID));
```

This will remove the items from source correctly.

Comment: This is crazy. You're very right, but the code _did_ compile. What in the world is going on here?!?

Comment: Oh boy. Apparently `Contains<T>(this IEnumerable<T>, Predicate<T>)` is actually an extension method in our libraries with a **gigantic freaking bug** in it. Thank you so much for making me look into that.

Comment: Gotta love gigantic freaking bugs.

Answer (score 1):

I might opt to tackle the problem a different way.

You said you do not have suitable implementations of equality inside the class. Maybe you can't change that. However, you *can* define an `IEqualityComparer<Model>` implementation that allows you to specify appropriate `Equals` and `GetHashCode` implementations external to the actual `Model` class itself.

```
var comparer = new ModelComparer();
var addableModels = newSourceOfModels.Except(modelsThatAlreadyExist, comparer);
// you can then add the result to the existing
```

Where you might define the comparer as

```
class ModelComparer : IEqualityComparer<Model>
{
     public bool Equals(Model x, Model y)
     {
         // validations omitted
         return x.ID == y.ID;
     }

     public int GetHashCode(Model m)
     {
         return m.ID.GetHashCode();
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
source.RemoveAll(source.Where(result.Select(r => r.ID).Contains(source.Select(s => s.ID))));
```

The goal of this statement is to make two enumerations of IDs, one for source and one for result. It then will return true to the where statement for each of the elements in both enumerations. Then it will remove any elements that return true.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is removing all the models which are the *same* between the two lists, not those which have the same *ID*. Unless they're actually the same instances of the model, it won't work like you're expecting.

Sometimes I use these extension methods for that sort of thing:

```
public static class CollectionHelper
{
    public static void RemoveWhere<T>(this IList<T> list, Func<T, bool> selector)
    {
        var itemsToRemove = list.Where(selector).ToList();
        foreach (var item in itemsToRemove)
        {
            list.Remove(item);
        }
    }

    public static void RemoveWhere<TKey, TValue>(this IDictionary<TKey, TValue> dictionary, Func<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>, bool> selector)
    {
        var itemsToRemove = dictionary.Where(selector).ToList();
        foreach (var item in itemsToRemove)
        {
            dictionary.Remove(item);
        }
    }
}
```